# laravel. Как отключить авторизацию и регистрацию?

Tags: laravel, auth

При заходе localhost/login отображается форма логина, там же можно и зарегистрироваться, но мое приложение пока не должно этого делать. Пробовал писать в роутах  `Route::get('login', 'HomeController@index');` , но почему-то это игнорируется, и форма все равно отображается. 
Где и что необходимо подправить, чтоб исключить возможность показа формы авторизации и регистрации всем пользователям?

Comment: routers.php покажите .

Answer (score 5):

Если ты использовал

```
php artisan make:auth
```

тогда у тебя добавилась строка к маршрутам

```
Auth::routes();
```

Закоменти ее и будет счастье.